# Create a dummy variable for a group based on rolling values of a categorical variable

Tags: r, dplyr, rolling-computation

Say I have the following `data`:

| date | name | rolename | firmname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-12-01 | John | helper | A |
| 2012-12-01 | John | helper | A |
| 2013-12-01 | John | helper | A |
| 2014-12-01 | John | helper | B |
| 2014-12-01 | John | senior manager | C |
| 2015-12-01 | John | helper | B |
| 2015-12-01 | John | senior manager | C |
| 2016-12-01 | John | senior manager | C |
| 2016-12-01 | John | senior manager | D |
| 2017-12-01 | John | helper | E |
| 2011-12-01 | Will | senior manager | A |
| 2012-12-01 | Will | senior manager | A |
| 2013-12-01 | Will | senior manager | Z |

I am trying to create a dummy variable for prior senior manager experience (`dummy_sm_exp`). That is, `dummy_sm_exp` equals 1 when the person **has prior experience as a senior manager in some other firm**, 0 otherwise. For instance, for the above data, a fifth column is created taking following values:

| date | name | rolename | firmname | dummy_sm_exp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-12-01 | John | helper | A | 0 |
| 2012-12-01 | John | helper | A | 0 |
| 2013-12-01 | John | helper | A | 0 |
| 2014-12-01 | John | helper | B | 0 |
| 2014-12-01 | John | senior manager | C | 0 |
| 2015-12-01 | John | helper | B | 0 |
| 2015-12-01 | John | senior manager | C | 0 |
| 2016-12-01 | John | senior manager | C | 0 |
| 2016-12-01 | John | senior manager | D | 1 |
| 2017-12-01 | John | helper | E | 1 |
| 2011-12-01 | Will | senior manager | A | 0 |
| 2012-12-01 | Will | senior manager | A | 0 |
| 2013-12-01 | Will | senior manager | Z | 1 |

Note that the dummy becomes equal to 1 only when a person has **prior** senior manager work experience at **another** firm. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you share the other example here and delete that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the most robust way of testing whether each person *has ever had management experience at a different company*, i.e. by summarising by person and company before testing lagged experience:

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- read.table(
  text = "date  name    rolename    firmname
          2011-12-01    John    helper  A
          2012-12-01    John    helper  A
          2013-12-01    John    helper  A
          2014-12-01    John    helper  B
          2014-12-01    John    'senior manager'    C
          2015-12-01    John    helper  B
          2015-12-01    John    'senior manager'    C
          2016-12-01    John    'senior manager'    C
          2016-12-01    John    'senior manager'    D
          2017-12-01    John    helper  E
          2011-12-01    Will    'senior manager'    A
          2012-12-01    Will    'senior manager'    A
          2013-12-01    Will    'senior manager'    Z",
  header = TRUE
) |>
  as_tibble()

df |>
  group_by(name, firmname) |> 
  summarise(manager = any(rolename == "senior manager")) |> 
  mutate(prev_man = as.integer(lag(cumany(manager), default = FALSE))) |> 
  left_join(df, by = c("name", "firmname")) |> 
  select(date, name, rolename, firmname, prev_man)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'name'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 13 × 5
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>    date       name  rolename       firmname prev_man
#>    <chr>      <chr> <chr>          <chr>       <int>
#>  1 2011-12-01 John  helper         A               0
#>  2 2012-12-01 John  helper         A               0
#>  3 2013-12-01 John  helper         A               0
#>  4 2014-12-01 John  helper         B               0
#>  5 2015-12-01 John  helper         B               0
#>  6 2014-12-01 John  senior manager C               0
#>  7 2015-12-01 John  senior manager C               0
#>  8 2016-12-01 John  senior manager C               0
#>  9 2016-12-01 John  senior manager D               1
#> 10 2017-12-01 John  helper         E               1
#> 11 2011-12-01 Will  senior manager A               0
#> 12 2012-12-01 Will  senior manager A               0
#> 13 2013-12-01 Will  senior manager Z               1
```

This will not distinguish between different senior manager roles at the same company. I'm not sure what John is doing in 2014 and 2015 - is he in both a helper and manager role in both years, so should get 0 in 2015 and 2016 as he hasn't changed company, or do you mean by this that he's switched between roles and should get 1? Will has not changed company in 2012 so gets a 0, but gets a 1 for 2013.

Comment: Hi @AndyBaxter, thanks for your answer. I tried your method. With this, the issue is that the dummy equals 1 in the second year of being a senior manager at the same firm. However, it should not be equal to 1 if the person is a senior manager at one single firm for infinite years unless they have prior senior manager experience. I have updated this question with new data as suggested. For your consideration, please.

Comment: I see what you mean now! So should only change to 1 after the end of at least 1 senior manager role? Will try with new data

Comment: precisely yes. For example, if I am doing my first senior manager role from years 2016-2018, the dummy should be 0 for all years. If I have a second role as a senior manager with some overlap in years, say 2017-2019, the dummy should be 1 across all second senior manager role years, i.e., from 2017 to 2019, since I have had a previous senior manager role in a previous company in 2016. Note that in my data, one person can have simultaneous senior manager roles at different companies.

Comment: Your output table doesn't make full sense then - John in 2015 is given a 1 for his previous senior manager role, but the previous role is in 2014, also in firmname C? Or is the "helper" role for B signifying a break in senior management?

Comment: Have tried an updated solution - see if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Andy, I have fixed it. See if it makes sense now? G

Comment: Looks good, and matches the new answer code I've put in edit. Try and see if it works on your data